Flow formula calculating incorrectly
I have a formula within flow that is calculating incorrectly. The formula is as follows:
{!$Record.Fee_Calc_1__c} - BLANKVALUE({!$Record.Fee_2__c}, 0) - BLANKVALUE({!$Record.Fee_3__c}, 0)

When performing the calculation manually the result is:
Fee Calc 1 = $29,701.85
Fee 2 = $20,831.89
Fee 3 = $15,623.92
$29,701.85 - ($20,831.89 - $15,623.92)
= $29,701.85 - $5207.97
= $24,493.88
But flow formula result = -$6,753.96
Am I missing something?  I have already used the brackets () to indicate order of operations.

Contrary to your claim, you haven't used parenthesis to indicate order of operations. The parens begin and end with each individual BLANKVALUE(), and there are no other parens, so your formula is 1 - 2 - 3.
You need either 1 - (2 - 3), or 1 - 2 + 3
i.e.
{!$Record.Fee_Calc_1__c} - 
(
    BLANKVALUE({!$Record.Fee_2__c}, 0) -
    BLANKVALUE({!$Record.Fee_3__c}, 0)
)



Thank you.  That has resolved it
